# History of Mathematical Biology - Resource Recommendations

Tags: mathematics, biology

Biology nowadays is filled with mathematics. Indeed, the field of mathematical biology is huge, and shows no sign of decay. But the mathematisation of biology is, to my knowledge, a recent phenomenon - dating to the early 20th century with the contributions of Ronald Fisher and his contemporaries.

Any resources detailing the history of this quantification would be fascinating to read; in particular, something which comments on the birth of mathematical biology and its relationship to biology done in the field or in the lab. But I can't find much! I'm looking for recommendations - books, articles, anything - on this aspect of the history and philosophy of biology.

Answer (score 3):

It is not *that* recent (apart from the name), before Fisher there were Bernoulli (1760), Malthus (1789) and Verhulst (1838), to name a few, although one might view them as pre-history. Here is a [PowerPoint](https://web.archive.org/web/20060901224506/http://www1.appstate.edu/%7Emarland/math_bio/Sunday_intro.ppt) that has the main highlights with dates. Rashevsky is generally credited with establishing the field, see [Hoffman, The Dawn of Mathematical Biology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01455). For book length treatments see [Essays on the history of mathematical biology by Israel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BYPK4E2), [Modeling Nature by Kingsland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226437280) (it focuses on population ecology), and [Stewart's The Mathematics of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematics_of_Life) for a mathematician's take.

For some philosophical treatments see books like [Otsuka's The Role of Mathematics in Evolutionary Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108727859) or [Instrumental Biology, or, the Disunity of Science by Rosenberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0226727262), and papers like [Dorato's Mathematical biology and the existence of biological laws](https://philpapers.org/rec/DORMBA) or [The mathematical theory of categories in biology by Varenne](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268068126_The_mathematical_theory_of_categories_in_biology_and_the_concept_of_natural_equivalence_in_Robert_Rosen).

Answer (score 1):

One of the first application of mathematics and logic to biology was classification. This was done by Aristotle and his terms still apply today - ie genus, species. These are logical terms taken from his *Organon* which detail the Aristotelian understanding of logic.

A good reference for this is the book by Rene Thom, *Semiophysics* where he also details the work of his own school to biological morphology and other aspects of Aristotelian biology. (This work he called catastrophe theory which Vladimir Arnold took umbrage at, and which he called singularity theory. And with good reason as many mathematical laymen misunderstood the term *catastrophe* - it's a change of form - nevertheless it did publicise the subject).